# Positive or negative boolean field names?

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling, boolean

A table's boolean fields can be named positively or negatively.

For example, calling a field:

```
"ACTIVE" , 1=on / 0=off 
or
"INACTIVE" , 0=on / 1=off
```

Is there a proper way to make this type of table design decision or is it arbitrary?

My specific example is a messages table with a bool field (private/public). This field will be set using a form checkbox when a user enters a new message. Is there a benefit in naming the field "public" vs "private"?

Comment: You should create another table, and implement a foreign key relationship - see my answer for details.

Comment: @AdilHussain Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. See my edit. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/266284)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I always prefer positive names to avoid double negatives in code. "Is not inactive" is often cause for a double take when reading. "Is inactive" can always be written as "if (!Active)" whilst taking advantage of built-in language semantics.

Comment: Some words themselves have negative meanings and not easy to find their positive counter-parts -- what is a better alternative for "isUnblocked"? "isAllowed"? I feel more comfortable putting "Block"/"UnBlock" rather than "Block/Allow" into GUI menu items. For this case I'm trying to use "isBlocked" in my code (which is a negative name) because "isUnblocked" is confusing and "isAllowed" is not consistent with the GUI menu.

Answer (score 19):

My personal preference:

- Use prefixes like "Is", "Has", etc. for Boolean fields to make their purpose clear.
- Always name variables in the *affirmative*. For Active/Inactive, I would name it IsActive.
- Don't make a bit field nullable unless you really have a specific purpose in doing so.

In your specific use case, the field should be named either IsPublic or IsPrivate--whichever name would result in a True answer when the user ticks the checkbox.

Comment: ...and what about built-in negatives of the design like "Lockout line"?

The device is inactive if the lockout line is high. isLockedOut means pretty much isDeviceInactive. But when I test the lockout line, I'm interested in isLockoutActive...

or, isWorkingCorrectly or isInFaultMode?

Comment: SF, I'm not sure I'm following your logic here, but I think you may have exceeded the purpose of a Boolean value and may need a Status field, with a lookup list of possible status values. The answer from OMG Ponies is the right one in that case.

Answer (score 3):

i would not disagree with some of the other answers but definitely avoid the incorrect answer which is not to put in double negatives always

Answer (score 1):

Always use positive names.

If use negative names, you very quickly get into double negation. Not that double negation is rocket surgery, but it's a brain cycle and those are valuable :)

Answer (score 1):

Always use positive.

It's simpler.

Take using the negation to the logical extreme: if InActive is better than Active, then why not InInActive, or InInInActive?

Because it would be less simple.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to handle these situations is to create a table to house the values associated with the column, and create a foreign key relationship between the two tables.  IE:

`WIDGETS` table:

- `WIDGET_ID`
- `WIDGET_STATUS` (fk)

`WIDGET_STATUS_CODES` table:

- `WIDGET_STATUS_CODE` (pk)
- `DESCRIPTION`

If possible, `WIDGET_STATUS_CODE` would be a natural key (IE: ACT for "Active", INA for "Inactive").  This would make records more human readable, but isn't always possible so you'd use an artificial/surrogate key (like an auto-number/sequence/etc).

You want to do this because:

- It's readable what status indicates (which was the original question)
- Future proof in the need to define/use more statuses
- Provides referencial integrity so someone couldn't set the value to 2, 3, 4, etc.
- Space is cheap; there's **nothing efficient about allowing bad data**

Comment: This is FAR less efficient than a simple bit field. What is the justification for doing this versus a simple bit field for a simple Boolean answer?

Comment: (a) Human readability of bare tables is not, IMHO, a goal of good database design. Otherwise, we would never use surrogate keys, and our databases would spend their entire lives doing string comparisons.

Comment: (b) I agree in principle w/r/t future-proofing for more values, but ONLY if there is a possible status that is NEITHER of the existing choices.

Naming a field something generic like "Status" when it really has to do *only* with Active/Inactive mode invites future abuse by shoehorning orthogonal attributes.

Eventually, this forces the design toward a m:n relationship that resembles a loosely-typed tag cloud. I'm not against tag clouds in general, but they break normalization, and that has consequences for the design.

Comment: (c) referential integrity is not needed for a Boolean/bit field, since the list of values is already restricted to 1/0.

Comment: +1, I tend to avoid bit data types, unless you have a table with many true/false flags that can't be combined into one status flag.  A single bit column in a table will still take a byte to store it.  I'll just use a check constraint if it is Status="A"ctive-"I"nactive, but use a FK and a table if you have more and/or strange values like "Q", etc.

Comment: (d) Space is cheap, but string comparisons are not, and neither are joins, especially when the number of potential values is two.

Comment: KM, a single bit field does *not* take a byte in MSSQL, unless it is the *only* bit field in the table. Not that 7 bits would be a huge waste, but just sayin'... Using varchar() fields with check constraints or foreign keys to other tables to store mere Boolean values is, IMHO, madness.

Comment: @richardtallent, calm down. I said: _A single bit column in a table will still take a byte to store it_ which is 100% true. Also, I never said that a Status column should be varchar(); a char(1) does just fine.  I've seen many people use the bit column very poorly.  They make multiple true/false columns to track a status, like for an invoice: isValid, isPaid, isPosted, isComplete; where a single status column with values "V", "P", "O", "C" and a FK to descriptive table works much better for me makes all the code simple one field to track status, not multiple.

Comment: @KM: Missed your point about bit--sorry. But using a char(1) as you've described only works if the values are **dependent**. Many times, database designers make the mistake of rolling independent status fields together by designing for an *ideal* workflow (e.g,assuming that isPosted implies isPaid, etc.). When a record in the real world jumps around, skips steps, etc., you lose important information. But my issue is specifically with implementing truly Boolean fields this way--a flexible design is good, but IMHO this breaks YAGNI and should not be a rule of thumb.

Answer (score -2):

Try to avoid boolean fields in databases alltogether.

One, the RM has a much better way to represent truth-valued information than via boolean fields : via the presence of a tuple in a table.

Two, boolean fields are very bad discriminators when querying.  It's virtually complete madness to index them, so when querying, the presence of boolean fields gives no benefit at all.

Comment: Boolean values can be poor discriminators, but that depends *entirely* on the distribution of 0 and 1 values.

Like any index, indexing a bit field adds an element of table lookup indirection if it is not the first-order column in a clustered index (which I'm not recommending), but indexing *does* avoid a table scan, so there *is* a performance benefit.

Meanwhile, using a FK to another table with a single value has exactly the performance limitation as an indexed bit field, and for the same reason, but joins add substantial additional overhead versus a bit index lookup.